# Dart: How to test a function that takes a function as a parameter?

Tags: flutter, function, unit-testing, dart, testing

i been trying to unit test a function that takes a function as a parameter the unit test returns null value on the function that im testing so may i ask how to unit test this kind of function in dart.

this is the function that i want to test

```
final result = await _appStateNotifier.guard(
      () => _authService.requestTempPassword(username: credentials.username),
    );
```

and this is how i test it but got an error `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Result<ErrorObject, String>>'`

```
when(() => mockAuthService.requestTempPassword(username: tCredentials.username))
              .thenAnswer((_) async => successMessage);

when(() => mockStateNotifier.guard(
              () => mockAuthService.requestTempPassword(username: tCredentials.username),
            ),
          ).thenAnswer((_) async => const Success(successMessage));

await notifier.onRequestTempPassword(credentials: tCredentials);
```

and this is the guard clause function

```
Future<Result<ErrorObject, T>> guard<T>(Future<T> Function() function) async {
try {
  final data = await future();
  return Success(data);
} on FailureException catch (e) {
  return Error(e);
} catch (e, s) {
  return Error(e);
}
```

}

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `Future<Result<ErrorObject, T>>` excludes the possibility of having a `Null` result. If you want to allow `Null`, then you need to make it nullable, see https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

I'm not fluent with Flutter, so the syntax might be off, but as far as I understand, you could change that to

```
Future<Result<ErrorObject, T>>?
```

in order to make it nullable. Let me know if I'm totally off with the syntax.

EDIT

It turns out that the solution finally applied was putting the when method in the setpup function before the test run, as @Ken Verganio described in the comment section.

Comment: i dont want it to be nullable i mean this code works in the emulator but in unit test it throws a null because theres wrong on how i wrote my test and i want to know whats wrong in my test or how to write the test in this case

Comment: @KenVerganio then you can use the assertion operator of `!` to specify that it's not nullable, see https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/

Comment: @KenVerganio I mean this section: https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/#the-assertion-operator

Comment: thank you for your time but i solve the problem by putting the when method in the setpup function before the test run

Comment: @KenVerganio thanks for the info. I have edited my answer accordingly.